# Editing file mounted via gvfs with emacs

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, ftp, mount, emacs

I want to edit a file on a ftp server (provided by the french IP Free).
Files are mounted on my comp via gvfs and I'd like to use emacs (23.1.1).
Here is what I get when I save after edit

```
Saving file /home/ugo/.gvfs/ftp as ***** on ftpperso.free.fr/index.htm...
basic-save-buffer-2: Opening output file: device or resource busy, /home/ugo/.gvfs/ftp as ***** on ftpperso.free.fr/index.htm
```

Editing locally and the moving file back to the gvfs directory is a workaround but I'd like to avoid this.
Any Idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If gvfs isn't working for you, a substitute is Emacs's own ftp interface, ange-ftp. Open your file as `/ftp:YOURUSERNAME@ftpperso.free.fr:index.htm`. This has the advantage of working even if your Emacs doesn't support gvfs. The main downside I can think of is that you'll have to type your password in Emacs, since AFAIK Emacs's password management hasn't been integrated with any external keyring program.

Comment: Thank you. `/ftp:YOURUSERNAME@ftpperso.free.fr:index.htm`